# What is the best way to learn Cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've messed around with iPhone development for a couple years now. I've done some contract work. I want to get into Cocos2D to develop a game idea that I have.

I was wondering what might be the best/quickest way to get up in running in cocos2d?

I've thought about a book, but I wondering if that is needed? I'm the type of guy that just wants to know what everything does and is suppose to be used for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/

Comment: I think the book is really good to get started in cocos2d. It won't explain what everything does and what it's purpose is (apparently that's what the OP want), but since cocos2d is open source, you can always have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

This blog is an awesome resource for starting out with Cocos2d iPhone development.  Great examples with full code.  It is also updated regularly.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Answer (score 1):

I second [Ray's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/). I've learned many a thing from there.

I'm also reading through [Learning Cocos2D](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321735625) which was actually written by Ray Wenderlich too (along with Rod Strougo). It covers both chipmunk and Box2D. Search the app store for 'Space Viking' - that's the app it build with you through the book.